# How do I update the GUI on the parent form when I retrieve the value from a Task?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I think I'm missing something obvious here, but how do I update the GUI when using a task and retrieving the value? (I'm trying to use await/async instead of BackgroundWorker)

On my control the user has clicked a button that will do something that takes time.  I want to alert the parent form so it can show some progress:

```
private void ButtonClicked()
        {
            var task = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                WorkStarted(this, new EventArgs());
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                WorkComplete(this, null);
                return true;
            });

            if (task.Result) MessageBox.Show("Success!");//this line causes app to block
        }
```

In my parent form I'm listening to WorkStarted and WorkComplete to update the status bar:

```
myControl.WorkStarting += (o, args) =>
                {
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
                        {
                            toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = true;
                            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Busy";
                        });

                };
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the app is hanging because "Invoke" is waiting for the GUI thread to become available which it won't until my "ButtonClicked()" call is complete.  So we have a deadlock.
What's the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Task.Run` to execute code on a background thread. The [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) specifies a pattern for progress updates, which looks like this:

```
private async void ButtonClicked()
{
  var progress = new Progress<int>(update =>
  {
    // Apply "update" to the UI
  });
  var result = await Task.Run(() => DoWork(progress));
  if (result) MessageBox.Show("Success!");
}

private static bool DoWork(IProgress<int> progress)
{
  for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
  {
    if (progress != null)
      progress.Report(i);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
  return true;
}
```

If you are targeting .NET 4.0, then you can use [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async); in that case, you would have to use `TaskEx.Run` instead of `Task.Run`. I explain on my blog [why you shouldn't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: I find very nice the progress updating. Do I need to invoke the progressbar or everything just happening the UI thread?

Comment: `Task.Run` is shortcut for `Task.Factory.StartNew` isn't it?

Comment: @BassamAlugili: The `Progress<T>` type will handle thread marshaling for you. Ideally, you should never have to `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` ever again.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yes, but the defaults are completely different. The details are in my blog post. So `Task.Run(() => ...)` is *not* the same as `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ...)`; it's the same as `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ..., CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default)` (with an extra `Unwrap` if necessary). Most importantly, you *have* to specify the `TaskScheduler` in `StartNew` to have the most reliable code.

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks, I'll have a look at it tonight, Is there any subscription link for your blog so that I'll get some kind of update when you write one?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: The feed is [here](http://feeds.feedburner.com/NitoPrograms). I try to get out about one a week, but sometimes that just doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

You're blocking the UI thread [Task.Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) blocks until the task is completed.

Try this.

```
private async void ButtonClicked()
{
     var task = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
            WorkStarted(this, new EventArgs());
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            WorkComplete(this, null);
            return true;
     });

     await task;//Wait Asynchronously
     if (task.Result) MessageBox.Show("Success!");//this line causes app to block
}
```

Comment: Hi @SriramSakthivel ^^ but this will freeze UI I do not think he want wait until the 5 second are done? or the await here will prevent that? I will test it

Comment: [You shouldn't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), as I explain on my blog.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It is working perfect! UI not blocked and after the await the code working as usual.

Comment: @StephenCleary I'll take a look at it when I get time(but sure), and one more thing to say your blog is awesome man. You have extraordinary skill to explain complicated things very easily :)

Comment: @BassamAlugili `StartNew` pushes the call to `ThreadPool` so UI will not be blocked

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes thanks I saw it by my self I have test it.

Comment: @Kim I can't reproduce the problem, this works perfectly for me. Post your updated code

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm working on Framework 4.0?  For the compile errors I'm getting "Cannot find all the types required by the 'async' modifier..."

Comment: If you can upgrade to .Net4.5 do it, else I'll provide different solution

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed my NuGet package and your code is working fine now.  However, I'm marking Stephan's answer as accepted because it's likely what other developers should be using if they come across this question.  Thanks for your help!